# Adding billing address to Adyen Web SDK

Tags: payment-gateway, adyen

Im using Adyen Web SDK. I'm trying to figure out how to add billing address as mandatory fields on the UI. Currently it looks like:

[image]

The adyen documentation is woeful, and there's no mention of how to add billing address fields. They have a section on customisations, but there are few options, and adyen don't even give a list of the possible values. See here: https://docs.adyen.com/developers/checkout/web-sdk/customization/settings

If I look in their documentation on localisation, it appears that billing address fields can be customised i.e. different translations. Yet there's no place where they say how to turn on billing address in the first place.

Has anyone successfully managed this? I've already put this question to adyen, with no reply yet.

Answer (score 1):

edit: removed previous answer, was incorrect.

It is not possible to collect address using the SDK. You would have to provide the address when initializing the Web SDK session: [`/paymentSession`](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v41/paymentSession).